# String to string and still getting error "cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'"

Tags: c#

I need help understanding why my program is throwing this error:

> Cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

when both list and `tVal` are strings.

I am getting this error at

```
List<string> testitems = new List<string>(tVal);
```

Please advise.

`abc` is an int array with some random numbers.

```cs
static void Main()
{
    string tVal = "";

    List<int> result = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < abc.Length; i++)
    {
        if (abc[i] == 7)
        {
            result.Add(0);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(abc[i]);
        }

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            tVal += item.ToString();
        }                            
    }

    List<string> testitems = new List<string>(tVal);
    //more code
}
```

Comment: You are calling [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Int32_) constructor overload. Apparently you meant `new List<string>() { tVal };`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `tVal` into a curly brackets , like this:

```
List<string> testitems = new List<string>() { tVal };
```

Official documentation for lists: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 3):

To add objects to a list you can use:

```
List<string> testitems = new List<string>() { tVal };  //(like @GSerg suggested in the comments)
```

Or:

```
List<string> testitems = new List<string>();
testitems.Add(tVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new List<string>(tVal)
```

You handed tVal in as the *1st constructor argument*. The closest match the compiler can find is `List<T>(Int32)`. Wich has a string -> Int conversion that is not valid.

This is not the way to initialize a collection! You can either:

- use the constructor that can take just about any generic collection as input (`List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`)
- Add the single element manually after creating the list (charbels solution)
- use the collection initializer syntax (as shown by Marci)